# Mysql Query give different counts first and second execution

Tags: mysql

open a new session on workbench and  trying to run this Query this query returns count '15'
at first execution and '4' ata its second execution why is it so ..

```
select count(id) 
from (
   select *,@num := if(@company_id = company_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,@company_id := company_id as dummy 
   from salebuild_ctl.company_contact 
   where id in (12352,59898,59899,59900,59901,59902,59903,59904,14047,15196,15197,41402,41403,41404,41405)  
   order by company_id,  date_created asc  
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 2;
```

Comment: What ist the result of `select @num;` before each call of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because first time you use `SET @num=0` but for next time when running query you are again not setting it to `0` so the for the second run it takes `@num=15`.

Do for running correctly before 2nd run `SET @num=0`